# Why are the eigenvectors of $A$ orthogonal when $AA^T=A^T A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Prof. Gilbert Strang mentions, in [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgC1l_6ySkc), that a matrix $A$ has orthogonal eigenvectors when $A^T A=AA^T$; i.e., when it is *normal*. Could someone provide me a (preferably intuitive) proof of this?

Comment: This [subsection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices) of the Wikipedia page on the Spectral Theorem has a proof sketch.

Comment: Actually that should be $A^* A = A A^*$, where $A^*$ is the Hermitian transpose (the conjugate transpose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result holds for every symmetric matrix S. The basic idea is that column space and row space of a symmetric matrix are equal and that row space and null space are orthogonal.

Given a pair of eigenvectors $x, y$ corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues $\alpha, \beta$, we have $Sx = \alpha x \Rightarrow (S-\alpha I)x = 0$ and $(S - \alpha I)y = (\beta - \alpha)y$. Therefore, $x$ is in the null space of $S-\alpha I$ and $y$ is in the column space of $S-\alpha I$. Since column space is equal to row space ($S-\alpha I$ is also symmetric), we have $x^Ty = 0$. The case of zero eigen values is trivial.